# Hiding A Comment Form With CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to hide a comment form (a div) with CSS `display: none;`but it doesn't seem to hide.  The div in question loads data with JavaScript.  Could anybody please help me and point out what actually I am doing wrong?

It is found at the very bottom of the page, the HyperComments form.  I've tried to apply the `display:none;`to the #`hc_root` div, but to no sucess.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try to give us a small but working example of the problem. That way, if your site's issue is fixed, this question will still be of use to future users.

Comment: When I look at the source code of the page, I do not find any hc_root there. There is hypercomments_widget, but the ID of the outer div is "hcc". Further, what is it you are trying to hide? Why would you put a comment form on the page and then hide it?

Comment: Err, just removing the link to your page is not what I meant in my earlier comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form is in an iframe. But you can hide the `div` with the `id` 'hypercomments_widge' by:

```
#hypercomments_widget {
    display: none;
}
```

(Or you can hide it using javascript.)

Comment: I used #hypercomments_widget { display: none; } too, but it is not working either!

Comment: If I reload [the page](http://functionn.blogspot.com/2012/06/hydrajs-javascript-library-providing.html) I can't see your `#hypercomments_widget { display: none; }`. Are you really sure you have added this rule?

Comment: sorry, my bad, did not save the file and push it again.  works now. thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The form is loaded into an iframe.

You must either

- put your CSS in the document that is loaded into that iframe
- hide the entire iframe: `#hypercomments_widget { display: none; }`

Comment: I used #hypercomments_widget { display: none; } too, but it is not working either!